# How to not deserialize contents of node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Say I have the following xml:

```
<Samples>
<Sample>
  <SomeStuff>
   <SomMoreStuff>.. </SomeMoreStuff>
  </SomeStuff>
</Sample>
<Sample>
  <SomeStuff>
   <SomMoreStuff>.. </SomeMoreStuff>
  </SomeStuff>
</Sample>
</Samples>
```

How can I deserilaize this but have all text inside of < Sample > remain as a string? I dont want to parse the contents of Sample

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Samples")]
public class Samples {

    [XmlElement("Sample")]
    public string[] Items{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to end of with a list like

```
[
  "<Sample><SomeStuff><SomMoreStuff>.. </SomeMoreStuff></SomeStuff></Sample>"
  "<Sample><SomeStuff><SomMoreStuff>.. </SomeMoreStuff></SomeStuff></Sample>"
]
```

Comment: If you have control of the XML, then, try wrapping the content inside <Sample /> with CDATA? Only suggestion I've got for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to load your Schema into the XmlDocument class and extract the inner or outer XML from it as a string.

One example could be:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(MySchema);
var sampleNode = xdoc.SelectNodes("//sample");

var sampleText = sampleNode.ToString();
// or
var sampleText2 = sampleNode.Item(0).OuterXml;
```

Use debugging to check the actual value of the node, to get the right string as output.

List example:

```
        var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(MySchema);
        var sampleNode = xdoc.SelectNodes("//sample");
        var sampleList = new List<string>();
        foreach (XmlNode item in sampleNode)
        {
            sampleList.Add(item.OuterXml); // or InnerXml - whatever value it is you need. 
        }
```

Comment: This is the route i've gone with. The CDATA also looks like it could work given some more time and tweaking since i can control the xml. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @Zholen .
Play around with the XmlDocument class, i'm sure there's more ways you can utilize it in your application.